# In COMSOL, how to calculate the volume integral of the squared magnitude of the electric field vector difference between two parameter combinations?

Tags: comsol

I'm using the AC/DC module, and I want to perform a parametric sweep on three parameters. For the sake of explanation, let's say the "delta" parameter takes values 0 and 5, and the "alpha" parameter takes values 10 and 20. After the calculations are completed, I would like to compute the squared difference of es.Ex between the cases where delta=0, alpha=10 and delta=0, alpha=20, and then perform a volume integration.

The approach I'd like to try is to see if it's possible to directly access es.Ex of a specific parameter combination within the completed dataset. For example, using u3 to represent the third parameter combination, I can calculate what I need using (u3.es.Ex - u4.es.Ex)^2. However, I have not found method to achieve this.

In addition, I also attempted to add another study to obtain two datasets. I want to see if I can achieve the desired result by merging the solutions from these two datasets.
[For example, in the figure, what I want to do is subtract the es.Ex values of sol3 and sol7, square the result, and then perform a volume integration. Similarly, I want to do the same for sol4 and sol8.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrYl0.png)